# tar stops with "Cannot stat: No such file or directory"

Tags: linux, tar

`tar` complains about not finding a directory that exists, and to which I have permissions. I have seen a number of similar questions, but all of them had to do wih the option `f` not being just before the output file. Not the case here.

```
gauthier@ionian:~ $ ls -l | grep cpdata
drwxrwxr-x   2 gauthier gauthier     4096 May 23 14:35 cpdata
-rw-rw-r--   1 gauthier gauthier 17609833 May 23 14:43 cpdata.tar.gz
gauthier@ionian:~ $ echo $HOME
/home/gauthier
gauthier@ionian:~ $ sudo tar -cvzf ~/cpd.tar.gz ~/cpdata​
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
tar: /home/gauthier/cpdata​: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
gauthier@ionian:~ $ tar --version
tar (GNU tar) 1.27.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by John Gilmore and Jay Fenlason.
gauthier@ionian:~ $ pwd
/home/gauthier
```

---

Content of the directory, and more:

```
gauthier@ionian:~ $ ls -l cpdata
total 45964
-rw-rw-r-- 1 gauthier gauthier    18507 Jun  3 21:27 cpconf.tar.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 gauthier gauthier 16469156 Jun  3 21:27 cplogs.tar.gz
-rw-r----- 1 gauthier gauthier    63227 Jun  3 21:28 dmesg
-rw-r----- 1 gauthier gauthier    61823 Jun  3 21:28 dmesg.0
-rw-r----- 1 gauthier gauthier    16725 Jun  3 21:28 dmesg.1.gz
-rw-r----- 1 gauthier gauthier    16878 Jun  3 21:28 dmesg.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 gauthier gauthier    17096 Jun  3 21:28 dmesg.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 gauthier gauthier    15672 Jun  3 21:28 dmesg.4.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 gauthier gauthier     4606 Jun  3 21:29 inotify-list.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 gauthier gauthier      554 Jun  3 21:28 install.vars
-rw-rw-r-- 1 gauthier gauthier 16469156 Jun  3 21:27 java-cpdir-logs.tar.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 gauthier gauthier        0 Jun  3 21:28 java-os-version.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 gauthier gauthier       66 Jun  3 21:28 java-os-whereis.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 gauthier gauthier       45 Jun  3 21:26 java-var-logs.tar.gz
-rw-r----- 1 gauthier gauthier    10492 Jun  3 21:28 kern.log
-rw-r----- 1 gauthier gauthier   202535 Jun  3 21:28 kern.log.1
-rw-r----- 1 gauthier gauthier     6320 Jun  3 21:28 kern.log.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 gauthier gauthier    23244 Jun  3 21:28 kern.log.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 gauthier gauthier     2970 Jun  3 21:28 kern.log.4.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 gauthier gauthier 13381734 Jun  3 21:29 lsof-list.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 gauthier gauthier    24594 Jun  3 21:28 ps-list.txt
-rw-r----- 1 gauthier gauthier    27381 Jun  3 21:27 syslog
-rw-r----- 1 gauthier gauthier    66630 Jun  3 21:27 syslog.1
-rw-r----- 1 gauthier gauthier     6816 Jun  3 21:27 syslog.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 gauthier gauthier     5268 Jun  3 21:27 syslog.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 gauthier gauthier    58584 Jun  3 21:27 syslog.4.gz
-rw-r----- 1 gauthier gauthier     5729 Jun  3 21:27 syslog.5.gz
-rw-r----- 1 gauthier gauthier     4866 Jun  3 21:27 syslog.6.gz
-rw-r----- 1 gauthier gauthier     8601 Jun  3 21:27 syslog.7.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 gauthier gauthier      105 Jun  3 21:28 uname-all.txt
gauthier@ionian:~ $ ls -l | grep cpdata
drwxrwxr-x   2 gauthier gauthier     4096 Jun  3 21:29 cpdata
-rw-rw-r--   1 gauthier gauthier 34586144 Jun  3 21:30 cpdata.tar.gz
```

Also interesting: I can produce a tar from the contextual menu in nautilus!

Comment: Did you try without the unnecessary _~/_ prefix? Just to be sure.

Comment: To clarify, you're telling `tar` to include the path prefix `home/gauthier/cpdata` for all archive members. Since `tar` tries to conserve the access rights and ownerships of `/home` and `/home/gauthier/` in this case also, it's possible that it fails to get that information depending on access rights above your home directory.

Comment: try without `sudo`, since you have permissions.

Comment: @ClassStacker: not working without `~/` either. @Isaac Hanson, not without `sudo` either.

Comment: And did you try both without absolute path and super user rights? Is this a directory mounted from a file server? Which file systems are involved?

Comment: It's all on a local disk. And I can compress from nautilus!